# Laravel eloquent returning wrong data

Tags: php, laravel

I have conditional data and it ignores that conditions while returning data:

**Works fine**

```
$orders = Order::where('user_id', $user->id)->with(['customer', 'laundry', 'driver', 'driver.user', 'progresses' => function($p){
  $p->orderby('created_at', 'asc');
}, 'progresses.progress', 'services'])->get();
```

**Return wrong data**

```
$orders = Order::where('user_id', $user->id)->with(['customer', 'laundry', 'driver', 'driver.user', 'progresses' => function($p){
                $p->orderby('created_at', 'asc');
            }, 'progresses.progress', 'services'])
            ->where('id', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
            ->orWhere('transport', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
            ->orWhere('amount', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
            ->orWhere('weight', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
            ->orWhere('total', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
            ->paginate(10);
```

#### Issue

The second query return all `orders` and ignores `where('user_id', '=', $user->id)`.

#### Question

1. why it ignore `where('user_id', '=', $user->id)`
2. How to fix it?

Comment: Why do you think it ignores where('user_id', '=', $user->id)? Did you check the SQL query?

Comment: @Ricardinho TBH if have no idea why :) do you? is yes please tell me.

Comment: I presume its the `orWhere()` that compromises the initial `where()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should group your search `LIKE` query here

```php
Order::with(
     [
       'customer', 
       'laundry', 
       'driver', 
       'driver.user', 
       'progresses' => function($p) {
          $p->orderby('created_at', 'asc');
       }, 
       'progresses.progress', 
       'services'
     ]
    )->where('user_id', $user->id)
    ->where(function($q) {
        $q->where('id', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
        ->orWhere('transport', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
        ->orWhere('amount', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
        ->orWhere('weight', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
        ->orWhere('total', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%');
    })->paginate(10);
```

So the query string is look like:

```sql
WHERE user_id = ? 
AND 
(id LIKE ? OR transport LIKE ? OR amount LIKE ? OR weight LIKE ? OR total LIKE ?)
```

It will ignore the `where('user_id', '=', $user->id)` because of `orWhere` on your search `LIKE` query

Comment: Hi, I just double checked now my `where('user_id', '=', $user->id)` works but data are not presented. :/

Comment: what do you mean, did you get no results?

Comment: sorry I found the issue :D